# VSCode autocompletes rule names without "@" symbol

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, typescript-eslint

When adding rules to the eslint config, with the typescript-eslint package, the rule names only autocomplete when I do not use the "@" symbol, but without the "@" symbol, the rules do not work. The typescript-eslint documentation clearly shows the rule names with the "@" prefix.

VSCode - 1.87.2
macOS - 14.1.1
Node - 20.11.1
NPM - 10.2.4
ESLint - 8.57.0
Typescript-ESLint - latest

Comment: please add version numbers and system info for all your things (VS Code, OS, ESLint, etc.)